# Product Slide show in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Hi i have tried to add a product in slide show on magento home page but it not working can you please give suggestion for How to add a product on slide show in magento?

Comment: which kind of products do u want to show in the slide show like new products, features products, sale products?

Comment: i want to add feature product in a slider? can u plz gve any example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is :

1. Create a static block (something/filename.phtml).
2. Load product collection in the static block and filter the products which you would want to see on the slider.
3. Create appropriate HTML markup for the section of the page.
4. Use a suitable jQuery / JavaScript plugin to render the slider.
5. Call the static block that was created in step 1, from the CMS Page meant for homepage. This can be done using Layout Updates Section.